# Screencast of selenium tests using Castro

Tags: selenium

I want to generate the screencast of the selenium tests. I read that Castro can be used for this but it can only be installed on Linux. Does anybody know about its variant for windows? If yes, please send the links.

Answer (score 0):

We at [TestingBot.com](http://testingbot.com) video record all Selenium tests by using C# and Microsoft Expression Encoder's [ScreenCapture class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.screencapture.screencapturejob%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

- For Java you can try Monte Media Screenrecorder - here's a [howto](http://massol.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Blog/ScreenRecordingForSelenium2)
- For the mentioned Castro find an [Intro here](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2009-12/automating-screencasts)